# Is it possible to have a different url for a different language

Tags: language, multi-language, language-switcher

Currently, I have a **multiple language** website. it's xxxx.nl. Its available in **Dutch** and in **English**.

I also own the **domain .eu**. Would it be possible to have the **English version** of the website on the **.eu domain** and the **Dutch version** on the **.nl domain** without making 2 completely different websites?

And also give customers the possibility to switch between the Dutch website and the English one just like the **language switcher** i have now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your current website is using two store views (one for english and one for dutch).
To set another store with a different domain you'll have to create a new website instead of a store view. This way you can use the same magento installation on the same server but with different domains.
Regarding the switch menu, that only comes as default for the store views but you can create a custom link on the menu later.

Comment: Oke so i need go launch a multistore in order for this to work?